# Regular expression for date and time

Tags: regex

Anybody can help compose regular expression for this logic?

```
MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm AM/PM 
MM/DD/YYYY hh AM/PM 
MM/DD/YYYY 
MM/YYYY 
YYYY
```

---

[Date templates]

```
M/D/YY 
M/YY 
M/YYYY 
M/D/YYYY 

MMM YY 
MMM YYYY 
MMMM YY 
MMMM YYYY 

YY/M 
YY-M 
YY.M 

YYYY/M 
YYYY-M 
YYYY.M 

YYYY 

YYYY/M/D 
YYYY-M-D 
YYYY.M.D 

M-D-YY 
M-YY 
M-YYYY 
M-D-YYYY 

M.D.YY 
M.YY 
M.YYYY 
M.D.YYYY 

MMM D[,] YY 
MMM D[,] YYYY 

MMMM D[,] YY 
MMMM D[,] YYYY 

D MMM[,] YY 
D MMM[,] YYYY 

D MMMM[,] YY 
D MMMM[,] YYYY
```

[Time templates]

```
hh:mm AM (or PM or A or P) 
hh AM (or PM or A or P) 
HH:mm 

YY two-digit year (00 => 2000, 10 => 2010)
```

Comment: **checkDate** - `/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/` **checkTime** - `/^(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})(:00)?([ap]m)?$/`

Comment: `^((0?[13578]|10|12)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[01]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1}))|(0?[2469]|11)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[0]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1})))$` example: 1/2/03 | 02/30/1999 | 3/04/00

Comment: what will make this complicated is the (probable) need for consistency in date separators, eg "MM/DD-YYYY" should probably be invalid?

Comment: @Mikhail What's the `[13578]` for? (as well as some other `[]`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you some hints:
You have different ways to specify a month: M, MM, MMMM

M means its a number, so you can write it like `[0-9]` (there are even more compact ways, but I think this requires the least explanation).

MM means you can have another digit, but this digit can obviously only be `1`, as `12` is the highest.

So we alter the expression: `1?[0-9]`. Which means the one is optional.

Is this correct? No, because it would e.g. accept `0` as a valid month. So alter it again.

`(1[0-2]|[1-9])` which means: either a `1` followed by another digit between 0 and 2, so 10, 11, 12 are accepted. The braces are there to create a group.

Now to accept `MMMM`

`(1[0-2]|[1-9]|January|February)` etc.

This can be further composed, e.g. for `MM/YYYY` and `YYYY`

`((1[0-2]|[1-9]|January|February)/)?<YYYY-Pattern>`

Also don't forget to match the start and the beginning:

`^((1[0-2]|[1-9]|January|February)/)?<YYYY-Pattern>$`

otherwise you'd match things like `abc MM/DD/YYYY bla`

If everything works, you should use non-capturing groups where you don't need to reference the contents of a group. So `^((1[0-2]|[1-9]|January|February)/)?<YYYY-Pattern>$` becomes `^(?:(1[0-2]|[1-9]|January|February)/)?<YYYY-Pattern>$` because you probably don't need to reference the group with the `/`. (However I think this is implementation dependent). To reference the groupse you probably want to give them names. Have a look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Well that's the way I compose regular expressions...

Don't give up, its going to be a longer expression, but not a very complex one.